# Having trouble converting a character string to hexidecimal in C

Tags: c, pointers, hex, decimal

I am having trouble with code I am writing to convert a decimal to hexadecimal.

```
void decToHex (char *decString){
    char hexVal[100];
    sprintf(hexVal,"%x", *decString);
    *decString = hexVal;
    return;
}
```

> compilation error: warning: assignment makes a pointer from an integer
>   without a cast (enabled by default); speaking of the line "*decString
>   = hexVal;" where I am trying to set my pointer value to the newly discovered hex value.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I have read through some other posts that said this could be an issue with the compiler, however we are required for our class to use the standard c99 compiler built into our putty server. Any ideas on how to do this? I also tried creating an array of ints based on the modulus 16 idea, but I had even more issues with that.

Comment: See this is why I try not to code for hours on end, I start making stupid mistakes. Thanks for the help guys, don't know what I was trying to accomplish with *decString = hexVal. I do have a question though, why would it be strcpy(decString,hexVal) and not strcpy(*decString,hexVal)? Sorry, as you can see still a little new on the pointer thing too.

Comment: strcpy need to get the address to store the copy of the string. The first `char` that is already stored there will not help it...

Comment: `strcpy()` needs a pointer for both the source and destination because it needs to know where to find and store the data in memory. Derefencing the pointer just gives you the value, which isn't helpful when the program wants to store something in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*decString` is a char. `hexVal` (in this context) is a pointer to char, so you try to store address in a char. hence the error.

Even if you will do `decString=hexVal`, it will not work, for 2 reasons: it will change `decString` only in the function, and `hexVal` is a local variable, so it's not valid outside of the function.

Instead of this, copy the string from `hexVal` to `decString`: `strcpy(decString, hexVal);`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a C string the way you've tried. Instead, you want:

```
strcpy(decString, hexVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `*decString = hexVal;` is problematic.  `decString` is a pointer to a `char`, so `*decString` represents a `char`.  However, `hexVal` is a `char*` (technically, it's `&hexVal[0]`).  You are trying to assign a *pointer* to a *character*.  Unless you are on an 8-bit platform, a pointer won't fit inside a character.  Also, the pointer is a pointer to a local variable, which means the pointer will be invalid once the function returns.  If you are trying to copy a string, use `strncpy()` instead.

To clarify your task, are you trying to convert the *string representation* of a decimal number into a hexadecimal *string representation*?  If so, you'll probably be more successful if you convert the string into an integer and then back into a string instead of trying to convert the string directly.  A combination of `sscanf()` and `sprintf()` should take care of it.

Comment: He doesn't need 8-bit platform. He needs only `CHAR_BIT`-bit platform.

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
*decString = hexVal;
```

The `*decString` is a `char`, so you are assigning a pointer to a `char`, hence the warning.

You can't assign strings in C; you have to copy them, in general.

However, you also need to specify the value to be converted, and ensure you provide enough space for the formatted value.  At the moment, you are taking the first character of `decStr` and converting that to hex, which is a little unusual as an interface (probably wrong, in fact).

You'd normally do that with something like:

```
void decToHex(int value, char *hexString)
{
    sprintf(hexString,"%x", value);
}
```

Note the changed interface.  This doesn't allow the function to check that it has enough space; sadly, placing the onus on the calling code is a long-standing (but troublesome) C tradition.  The more secure way to do it would use `snprintf()` from C99:

```
int decToHex(int value, char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    return snprintf(buffer, buflen, "%x", value);
}
```

This tells you how long the string was, or how long the buffer should have been if there wasn't room for all the data (except on Windows where it returns -1 when the converted string is too long).  The string should be null-terminated (beware MSVC) and should never overflow the buffer specified by `buffer` and `buflen`.  Setting `buffer` to NULL should, in principle, allow you to find out how big a buffer you need (beware MSVC again).

You'd normally call it like this:

```
char buffer[20];

if (decToHex(314159265, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) >= sizeof(buffer))
    ...oops - conversion failed...
```

or, more lazily:

```
 char buffer[32];  // Bigger margin for error

 decToHex(314159265, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```